# Overlay a shape into a gridded shape and determine the percentage of each cell that are overlapped

Tags: raster, shapefile, overlay

I would like to know how I can overlay a shapefile (A) into another gridded shapefile (B) and extract the information about which shapefile (A) polygons falls in each cells (B).
And, more specifically, I would like to know how I can determine the percentage of each cell that are overlapped by a shapefile.

[image: Shapefile A]

[image: Shapefile B]

Comment: what software options do you have access to?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using ArcMap:

- Make sure that every square is a polygon feature with a unique ID number.
- Perform a Union of the new clipped-grid.shp and the original polygons.
- The resulting union.shp should tell you the ID of the original square that was clipped, and the name of the polygon that overlapped it.
- Create a new column "Areas" and use Calculate Geometry to calculate the area of every feature.
- Create a second column called "Percentage" and populate it using Field Calculator: [Percentage] = [Areas] / X * 100 (where x is the size of the original square.)

Comment: This answer is pretty much what I would do, but I'm not sure why the Clip operation is included. Theoretically it should definitely *not* be, since one may be wanting to know which cells are not overlapped at all by the polygons.